# unoconv is not working in python

Tags: python, apache2, python-2.7

I've an issue while using unoconv to convert docs to html from a Python script.

It works perfectly when I run the script or the unoconv commands as root, but it fails when I do the same from other user. I had installed Ubuntu 13.04 Server and unoconv packages via apt-get install. I executed the python script as an ordinary (not root) user

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(["unoconv","-f","html","-o","/var/www/project/tagging/templates/documents","/var/www/project/media/resume1.doc"])
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

`ls -l` give the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-54-194-10-89:/var/www$ ls -l
total 183184
drwxr-xr-x 24 www-data www-data      4096 Aug 31 15:20 project
```

project has group and ownership as www-data

If anyone who can help me with this issue it would be appreciated.

Comment: It will display that process.

Comment: Try what I have given. I am sure that'sgoing to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before going to do that **you need to start the unoconv listener** then only it will start.
open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and start the listener as

```
unoconv --listener
```

Then try again with your operation of conversion.

**NOTE:** make sure that no other process using the listener, If any process do so , kill that process to assign the listener to current conversion.

hope that helps.

Comment: how to check whether process using listener in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling from Python, this is an easier solution:

```
import os
import subprocess

# Copy the environment, and add home to the enviornment
env = os.environ.copy()
env['HOME'] = '/tmp'

p = subprocess.Popen(["unoconv","-f", "html", "-o", "output.html", 
   "input1.doc"], env = env)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

The issue is that unoconv needs a writeable HOME directory in order to start the listener. When you're calling from django, that HOME directory is not set. Setting it manually to `/tmp` solves this issue.